# Default Routing in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, routes, patch

According to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html:

```
HTTP Verb   Path     Action     Used for
GET /photos index    display  a list of all photos
GET /photos/new  new     return an HTML form for creating a new photo
POST    /photos create   create   a new photo
GET /photos/:id  show    display a specific photo
GET /photos/:id/edit     edit   return an HTML form for editing a photo
PATCH/PUT   /photos/:id  update update a specific photo
DELETE  /photos/:id destroy  delete a specific photo
```

How does rails know when a PATCH/PUT REST is received. I understand the get/post but PATCH/PUT I cannot figure it out. Is something being done internally, like in the input.

Comment: read here [PATCH is the new primary HTTP method for updates](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/2/25/edge-rails-patch-is-the-new-primary-http-method-for-updates/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails figures out which method to call based on whether the form submitted is a form for a new record that has not yet been saved or for a record that already exists in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Read about "resource routing" in the document you referenced at the top of your post.
Also, run `rake routes` to see how rails is currently configured to route.

Comment: There is no details on how this PATCH request is made in the DOC.

Comment: Here's a [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#how-do-forms-with-patch-put-or-delete-methods-work-questionmark) to an example.

Answer (score 0):

In The Terminal Type:

```
$rake routes
```

and hit enter

Prefix Verb URI Pattern Controller#Action

root GET  /          welcome#index